# How to get the GL library/headers?

Tags: c++, opengl

```
#include <gl\gl.h> 
#include <gl\glu.h> 
#include <gl\glaux.h>
```

This is an example, but where to get GL headers?

Comment: https://www.khronos.org/registry/khronos_headers.zip

Comment: OpenGL is not a library. It is a specification. See [Khronos OpenGL overview](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/) The OpenGL API is implemented by the graphics driver.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

#### Windows

On Windows you need to include the `gl.h` header for OpenGL 1.1 support and link against OpenGL32.lib. Both are a part of the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx). In addition, you might want the following headers which you can get from http://www.opengl.org/registry .

- [`<GL/glext.h>`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glext.h) - OpenGL 1.2 and above compatibility profile and extension interfaces..
- [`<GL/glcorearb.h>`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glcorearb.h) - OpenGL core profile and ARB extension interfaces, as described in appendix G.2 of the OpenGL 4.3 Specification. Does not include interfaces found only in the compatibility profile.
- [`<GL/glxext.h>`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glxext.h) - GLX 1.3 and above API and GLX extension interfaces.
- [`<GL/wglext.h>`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/wglext.h) - WGL extension interfaces.

#### Linux

On Linux you need to link against libGL.so, which is usually a symlink to libGL.so.1, which is yet a symlink to the actual library/driver which is a part of your graphics driver. For example, on my system the actual driver library is named libGL.so.256.53, which is the version number of the nvidia driver I use. You also need to include the `gl.h` header, which is usually a part of a Mesa or Xorg package. Again, you might need `glext.h` and `glxext.h` from http://www.opengl.org/registry . `glxext.h` holds GLX extensions, the equivalent to `wglext.h` on Windows.

If you want to use OpenGL 3.x or OpenGL 4.x functionality without the functionality which were moved into the `GL_ARB_compatibility` extension, use the new `gl3.h` header from the registry webpage. It replaces `gl.h` and also `glext.h` (as long as you only need core functionality).

Last but not the least, [`glaux.h`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/opengl/header-files) is not a header associated with OpenGL. I assume you've read the awful NeHe tutorials and just went along with it. **GLaux** (aka [Auxiliary Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/opengl/using-the-auxiliary-library) for *OpenGL Programming Guide*) is a horribly outdated library which preceded **GLUT**. Written by SGI in 1993 and then ported to Win32 by Microsoft, it was used mostly for loading uncompressed bitmaps. Use something better, like **libPNG**, which also supports alpha channels.

Comment: To Note:  the Windows SDK version above is Windows 7.  Just check for the most recent version of the Windows SDK, (now 8.1 and soon to be 10).  Check the documentation for backwards and forward compatibility.

Comment: What about MacOS ?

Comment: in Windows 7 x64, for some reason I unknow including `gl.h` and `glu.h` doesn't work, just including `windows.h`

Answer (score 50):

### Debian Linux (e.g. Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get update
OpenGL: sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
```

### Windows

Locate your Visual Studio folder for where it puts libraries and also header files, download and copy lib files to lib folder and header files to header. Then copy dll files to system32. Then your code will 100% run.

Also **Windows**: For all of those includes you just need to download `glut32.lib`, `glut.h`, `glut32.dll`.

Comment: debian/ubuntu/other derivatives != linux

Comment: This answer is 10 years old but still helped me (Ubuntu LTS).

Comment: @CoatedMoose just don't say what is not, we don't need to know that something is not, could you kindly someday say what it actually is??

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio :

```
//OpenGL
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32")
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32")
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
```

Headers are in the SDK : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\gl

Answer (score 5):

What operating system?

Here on Ubuntu, I have

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/include/GL/gl.h 
mesa-common-dev: /usr/include/GL/gl.h
$
```

but not the difference in a) capitalization and b) forward/backward slashes. Your example is likely to be wrong in its use of backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, they are installed with the platform SDK (or Visual Studio). However the header files are only compatible with OpenGL 1.1. You need to create function pointers for new functionality it later versions. Can you please clarify what version of OpenGL you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers above, in regards to linux, are either incomplete, or flat out wrong.

For example, /usr/include/GL/gl.h is not part of    mesa-common-dev or has not
been for many years.

At any rate, for a more current answer, these two packages are important:

https://mesa.freedesktop.org/archive/mesa-20.1.2.tar.xz

ftp://ftp.freedesktop.org/pub/mesa/glu/glu-9.0.1.tar.xz

The glu.h is part of glu itself:

```
GL/glu.h
GL/glu_mangle.h
```

Mesa is evidently significantly larger. Its headers are
a bit variable, I suppose, depending on the flags given
to meson, but should include these typically:

```
KHR/khrplatform.h                                                                                                         
EGL/eglplatform.h                                                                                                         
EGL/eglext.h                                                                                                              
EGL/eglextchromium.h                                                                                                      
EGL/eglmesaext.h                                                                                                          
EGL/egl.h                                                                                                                 
vulkan/vulkan_intel.h
gbm.h
GLES3/gl31.h
GLES3/gl3ext.h
GLES3/gl3.h
GLES3/gl32.h
GLES3/gl3platform.h
xa_composite.h
xa_tracker.h
xa_context.h
GLES2/gl2.h
GLES2/gl2platform.h
GLES2/gl2ext.h
GLES/gl.h
GLES/glplatform.h
GLES/glext.h
GLES/egl.h
GL/gl.h
GL/glx.h
GL/osmesa.h
GL/internal
GL/internal/dri_interface.h
GL/glcorearb.h
GL/glxext.h
GL/glext.h
```

Hope that helps anyone finding an answer this question in
the future; compiling dosbox needs this, for instance, due
to SDL opengl.

Answer (score 0):

2022 Update: On Windows, **the platform SDKs and Visual Studio no longer install gl.h anywhere**.

I have installed Visual Studio 2017, 2018, 2019, and 2022, and SDKs for Windows 8, 10, and 11. A search of my entire disk for "gl.h" produces no results. Searching for "windows.h" locates it correctly in VS's /include directories.

Googling how to acquire those header files simply instructs you to install VS and the SDKs.