# Writing OpenGL applications in C++

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I am a linux user. I write OpenGL applications in python but i am going to write OpenGL applications in C++ , but i have a problem. there is no 'GL' folder in '/urs/include' directory and i have not acces to OpenGL headers. what should i do? is there not installed packages?

Comment: Check out [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933027/how-to-get-the-gl-library-headers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install it.

For Ubuntu, I *think* the command is:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
```

As this installs everything `freeglut` depends on.

For other linux distros (I run Arch Linux), just search Google for **opengl headers {distro}**.

Comment: And `libglw1-mesa`, which is the most important of all. It's an implementation (very well known) of the OpenGL API.

Comment: Thanks. I don't run Ubuntu any more, so I knew something was wrong with the command list ;)

Comment: Blender doesn't use Ubuntu anymore **='(** Windows?

Comment: Ubuntu has become a netbook distro IMO, same with GNOME's layout. Arch Linux is my distro of choice now, as at least I can install XFCE without any problems on it...

Comment: I miss XFCE, it's been so long.

Comment: @Blender: The same goes for Fedora. Ubuntu and Fedora: Dumbed down Distributions :( On my own machines I run either Gentoo or Arch. Gentoo is great for developers as you have the development for every installed library available without having to install additional developer packages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install mesa (if you don't have a graphics card with decent drivers).  Depending on your distro, there should be an easy way to do this.  You'll be interested in mesa-common-dev or libmesa.

On gentoo with an nvidia graphics card, I installed nvidia-drivers and I get the header files with it.

On ubuntu, I installed mesa-common-dev.