# Can't run OpenGL example in SDL2

Tags: opengl, sdl

I just installed SDL2, and am having a bit of trouble getting some of the test examples to run, specifically testgl2.c, which can be found in the test directory of the SDL2.0.0 source.

At first, I did my ./configure; make; sudo make install, then went to the test directory and ran make. It failed part way through, but the testgl2 executable was still built. When I ran it, I receive the error "No OpenGL support on this system.". Looking into the source, it looks like HAVE_OPENGL is not getting defined.

I found [this thread](http://www.pascalgamedevelopment.com/showthread.php?5819-SDL-X11-driver-not-configured-with-OpenGL) which told me to install libglu1-mesa-dev, and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933027/how-to-get-the-gl-library-headers) which also said to install freeglut3-dev and mesa-common-dev. I installed all of these, ran a make clean for the SDL installation, and did the ./configure; make; sudo make install, remade the test, but I still receive the same error message when running testgl2. I did noticed that the line

*checking for OpenGL (GLX) support... no*

changed to yes after I installed the packages.

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, with an integrated graphics card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At first, I did my ./configure; make; sudo make install, then went to the test directory and ran make.

I think you missed a step.

Do the top-level `configure/make/make install`, then repeat for the `configure` script in the `test` directory.

It looks like only `test/configure` will generate a Makefile with `HAVE_OPENGL`.

Comment: Yup, that worked. I did run a ./configure in the test directory before, but that was before I installed the required OpenGL packages, and forgot to run it again afterwards. Thanks!