# fatal error: GL/gl.h: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

So I am trying to get my first c++ app to run but i keep getting this error. The error originates from the `freeglut_std.h` file.

I have downloaded the freeglut 3.0.0 MinGW Package and placed the files inside their respective directories in my MinGW installation folder but there is no file called gl.h.
I have added the libraries to my project properties

I have checked the question that this should be a duplicate of but the solution given there, install Windows SDK, did not fix my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the GL library/headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933027/how-to-get-the-gl-library-headers)

Comment: The answer in that question only says I should download the Windows SDK (which I have). There is nothing on the 'getting started' guides I have read that talk about getting the gl.h separately somewhere.
Downvoting a question because it might have been answered somewhere else, in a question that does not show up if you google my error is a bit rash imo. It's not like I didn't search before i asked...

Comment: Didn't downvote you, just pointed to an answer, which could answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Normally there's no need to download `GL/gl.h`; OpenGL is part of the Windows ABI contract, which means that every compiler toolchain that targets the Windows API must provision for compiling the OpenGL version that's specified for the Windows ABI. That would be OpenGL-1.1

If your MinGW installation lacks the `GL/gl.h` header, something is broken in your particular installation. Note that in some Linux distributions you may have to install the development support files separately. But with MinGW the OpenGL headers should be part of the standard installation.